# Nested Projects in php IDE

Tags: eclipse, wordpress

I'm not a programmer but coding some plugins for WordPress for my own usage. I want to learn how you professionals organize your projects.

I make entire WordPress directory a project in my PHP IDE(previously I use NetBeans, now newly switched to Flash Builder for PHP which can work with Eclipse or Zend ), because all plugins are dependencies of WordPress. The whole source directory is in localhost's htdhost/

It would be more convenience if I can make each plugin a project under Main WordPress Project, then, use github for each plugin's local private versions. Is this the right way to do things? Or would it mess up the whole thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse, most "new project wizards" let you choose the location of the new project created. You can start by creating a project "WordPress" with the default location (let's call it "C:\Users\Jenny\Workspace"), then create another project "A" but change its default location (in the first page of the new project wizard under the name of the project in most "new project wizards" in Eclipse) to "C:\Users\Jenny\Workspace\WordPress". You new project will be in your Eclipse Project Explorer view twice:

1. as a regular project
2. as a folder inside the WordPress project

Then, you can work as usual with your projects.